# Good practice to isolate IOC in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

I am wondering if are there any good code practice to use in order to isolate IOCs on my `App.cs` `RegisterTypes` since it's getting bigger. Would it be possible to create a generic / base class to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can break your code into modules, instead of registering all of them in one place. Most modern IoC's have that feature.

Comment: @AramKocharyan Alright, I will check this out. Thanks.